# Tuples implementation

Tags: c#, tuples, design-decisions

Sorry if it's a duplicate. I couldn't find a full explanation on that matter.
And the MSDN is vague as usual...

Does the .Net tuples provide a usable implementation for equals and GetHashCode out of the box?
(And consequently the == operator)

Can I expect a tuple to compare all it's item by default or must I provide an IEqualityComparer as is shown here [net-tuple-and-equals-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084412/net-tuple-and-equals-performance)?

Can it be reliably applied as dictionary keys?

I've ran a small test :

```
Tuple<DateTime, string, int> test3 = new Tuple<DateTime, string, int>(DateTime.Now.Date, "1", 1);
Tuple<DateTime, string, int> test4 = new Tuple<DateTime, string, int>(DateTime.Now.Date, "1", 1);

Console.WriteLine(test3 == test4);
Console.WriteLine(test3.Equals(test4));

Console.ReadKey();
```

The result was false and true. I guess the equals is implemented but not the operator. Does this mean that the == operator compares references? Also, I couldn't find the overload with the IEqualityComparer(framework version 4).

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the `==` operator is entirely separate from the `Equals` method... whereas `Equals` and `GetHashCode` need to be aligned.

Comment: MSDN is vague in one particular area, but it still provides enough information for you to answer *most* of your questions, such as what `==` will do.

Comment: @Grant Winney many thanks. 
The part that confuses me is EqualityComparer<Object>.Default. Will it work for all cases, assuming that the Items of the tuple are not custom classes?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom classes"? Basically, `EqualityComparer<object>.Default` will call the regular `Equals(object)` code... so it's up to how the relevant classes override that.

Comment: Got a bit confused by the implementation. I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx), you can see that:

- `GetHashCode` is overridden, although the details are not clearly documented. (It *could* return 0 for all instances, for example.)
- [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270346(v=vs.110).aspx) is overridden in a well-documented way, delegating to the equality comparer of the component types.
- The `==` operator is *not* overloaded - so yes, it will have perform regular reference-identity comparison

Although it's not clearly documented, the *compile-time* component types have to be equal, not just the *execution-time* component types. So for example:

```
var t1 = new Tuple<object, object>("foo", "bar");
var t2 = new Tuple<string, string>("foo", "bar");
Console.WriteLine(t1.Equals(t2)); // False
```